# Symfony inject some entity into listener

Tags: php, symfony

Need some advice.
I want to update article which is now seen.
First i inject EM into listener. But parse url to get article id for load article not pretty for symfony, as it seemed to me.

```
services:
    app.articles.action_listener:
        class: FrontendBundle\EventListener\ArticleListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

Is there any options for how to get the entity like its happen in the controller ?

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}", requirements={"page": "\d+"}, name="article_view_full")
 *
 * @param Article $article
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function viewAction(Article $article)
```

**UPDATE**

```
/**
 * Class ArticleListener
 * @package FrontendBundle\EventListener
 */
    class ArticleListener
    {
        /**
         * @type EntityManager
         */
        private $manager;

        /**
         * ArticleListener constructor.
         *
         * @param EntityManager $manager
         */
        public function __construct(EntityManager $manager)
        {
            $this->manager = $manager;
        }

        /**
         * @param $event
         */
        public function onKernelController($event)
        {

            $controller = $event->getController();

            if (!is_array($controller)) {
                return;
            }

            if ($controller[0] instanceof ArticlesController && $controller[1] == 'viewAction') {
                // THIS IS THE FULL ARTICLE VIEW. HERE I NEED TO GET CURRENT ARTICLE INSTANCE AND UPDATE VIEWS COLUMN IN DB. 
            }
        }
    }
```

Thx for any help.

Comment: Can we see your ArticleListener ? Why don't you update your entity in this listener ?

Answer (score 0):

you can parse the service container as an argument

```
arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager','@service_container']
```

and then get the parameters...

```
 public function __construct( $em, Container $container     ) {
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->container    = $container;
    $rq                 = $this->container->get( 'request_stack' );
    $rq                 = $rq->getCurrentRequest();
    $parameters         = explode( '/', $rq->getRequestUri() );
```

you can also get the request from event:

```
$request = $event->getRequest();
```